# How to hide overlapping divs and not remove the content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `home.html` which has the following `div`

```
<div id="feature" class="feature">
</div>
```

I have n-numbered different buttons displayed as

```
         <button id="search" class="btn btn-large navigator-button navigator-icons">
                <i class="icon-search icon-large"></i>
                search
            </button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button id="playlist" class="btn btn-large navigator-button navigator-icons">
                <i class="icon-list icon-large"></i>
                playlists
            </button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button id="settings" class="btn btn-large navigator-button navigator-icons">
                <i class="icon-cog icon-large"></i>
                settings
            </button>
          </li>
          <li>
              <button id="queue" class="btn btn-large navigator-button navigator-icons">
                  <i class="icon-cog icon-play-circle"></i>
                  queue
              </button>
```

When I click on any buttons, the content associated to that click is displayed in `<div id="feature" class="feature">`

But currently, I just do the `jQuery.load()` and wipe out anything existing under `<div id="feature">`

**Disadvantage?**

- I have build those pages every time
- I do not retain the state of earlier page, for example, the search results user searched for

**What I want?**

- I need a way so that based on the click of the page, the page associated to current click loads while hiding the other pages corresponding to other button clicks
- I am not sure how to do that with jQuery, I am very new to it

Please let me know what best I can do to achieve the above
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use the hide() and show() functions, they don't modify the DOM.

http://api.jquery.com/show/

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

e.g.

```
$('#feature .content1').hide();
$('#feature .content2').show();
```

Comment: I liked the idea and shuffled around my `HTML` and `Javascript(jQuery)` and it seems to work, thank you @tpolyak for guiding in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use jquery-ui tabs, from what you described.   It's pretty easy to use.

You use UL and LI to define your tab buttons, and a list of DIVs to define each tab page.   There is some naming convention, but the rest is handled by jquery-ui.